# Does app need to worry about BLE connection interval?

Tags: connection, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've inherited some BLE code that I'm trying to figure out, and ran across something strange.

The Windows/Python application works by sending commands over a USB/Serial interface to a BlueTooth dongle that does the actual work (nothing strange there).  The original developers (who have long since disappeared from the face of the earth) stores the BLE connection interval, and then makes sure to not send the next command to the dongle until at least {connection interval} milliseconds have elapsed since the last command was sent.

To me, that sounds like a mis-use of the connection interval.  Is there any reason to use the connection interval to "spread out" commands being sent to the dongle?

Answer (score 0):

No your data flow control should never be designed around the connection interval. With GATT you have that a new request is sent after the previous's response has arrived. With L2CAP CoC there is flow control built-in. Write Without Response and Notifications can usually use the link layer's flow control, which is implemented in different ways on different Bluetooth stacks.